# Ограничить ширину и высоту div. HTML

Tags: html, css

подскажите пожалуйста, как ограничить длину и высоту div, так что бы он не расстягивался, пробывал пошалить в css бесполезно, вот код

```
.shop{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-top: 200px;
    border-width: 200px;
}
```

Писал уже все подряд от не знания(((

```
<div id="product_1" class="shop">
    <img src="img/product/uplay/far_cry4.png">
    <h4>Far Cry 4</h4>
    <p>Купить аккаунт с игрой за 10 рублей!</p>
</div>
```

Вопрос: **Ограничить div что бы из него не выходили эллементы**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.shop{
    max-width: 200px;
    max-height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-top: 200px;
    border-width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.img-wrapper {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.img-wrapper img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.text-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}
h4 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<figure id="product_1" class="shop">
   <div class="img-wrapper">
      <img        src="http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/farcry/images/7/73/FC4_KEYART_PACK-610x722.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140515173131">
   </div>
    <figcaption class="text-wrapper">
      <h4>Far Cry 4</h4>
      <p>Купить аккаунт с игрой за 10 рублей!</p>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: @pavel1787mego, спасибо, но мне не нужно что-то взамен, я помог, потому что была возможнось помочь

Comment: как дела с магазом :D

Comment: Можно бы семантики c figure

Comment: @Duoxx, да можно в качестве враппера использовать для картинки и figure, но я ипользовал div, но всё можно поменять, зависит от желания

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `max-height` и `max-width` для ограничения.
Для того, чтобы не отображалось за пределами `overflow:hidden`

Answer (score 0):

Всем внутренним элементам выставьте: `width:100%; height:100%;`

Comment: Не подскажите, что такое weight?

Comment: weight - это ширина елемента

Comment: @ Yuriy Chaban а мне казалось, что  weight - это вес =)

Comment: @YuriyChaban сомневаюсь

Comment: я хотел написать width а написал weight , прошу прощения, неусмотрел

Comment: @Cheg Вы правы, исправил

Answer (score 0):

Приблизительно так... https://jsfiddle.net/0nrpranv/2/

```css
.shop {
width:200px;
height:200px;
border:1px solid red;
padding:5px 5px 5px 0px;
}
.shop img {
width:80px;
height:100px;
float:left;
margin-right:5px;
}
.shop h4 {
margin-top:0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="product_1" class="shop">
    <img src="img/product/uplay/far_cry4.png">
    <h4>Far Cry 4</h4>
    <p>Купить аккаунт с игрой за 10 рублей!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Выстави контейнеру эти значения:

```
width:800px;
max-width:800px;
margin-left:auto !important;
margin-right:auto !important;
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]